# Exception: error occurred during batching: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

```
.
select
o.name as "Network Element Name",
(SELECT  CASE                 WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=8090328832013865599 /* RNC */ 
                              THEN           'RNC'
                              WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=8090328832013865600 /* Node B */ THEN
                               'Node B'
                              WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=5100558796013838330 /* BTS */ THEN
                               'BTS'
                               WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=5100558796013838331 /* BSC */THEN
                               'BSC'
                               END
            FROM nc_objects nt ,nc_references r 
           WHERE r.reference = nt.object_id)as "Network Element Type" from nc_objects o;
```

Comment: Your sub query for a column on the SELECT is returning more than 1 row. It should only return a single row. But not sure the sub query is even required.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It'd be super wonderful if you could describe what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried to solve your issue and where exactly you're stuck, instead of just pasting your code and hope someone picks up the pieces for you!

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the subquery returns more than one value. 
If you only have to return a value you must limit it using:

```
ROWNUM = 1
```

Otherwise check the join:

```
r.reference = nt.object_id
```

Example:

```
select o.name as "Network Element Name",
(SELECT  CASE                 WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=8090328832013865599 /* RNC */ 
                              THEN           'RNC'
                              WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=8090328832013865600 /* Node B */ THEN
                               'Node B'
                              WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=5100558796013838330 /* BTS */ THEN
                               'BTS'
                               WHEN nt.OBJECT_TYPE_ID=5100558796013838331 /* BSC */THEN
                               'BSC'
                               END
            FROM nc_objects nt ,nc_references r 
           WHERE r.reference = nt.object_id
             and rownum = 1) as "Network Element Type" from nc_objects o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a bit, but perhaps this is all you need:

```
select nt.name as "Network Element Name"
     , case nt.object_type_id
          when 8090328832013865599 then 'RNC'
          when 8090328832013865600 then 'Node B'
          when 5100558796013838330 then 'BTS'
          when 5100558796013838331 then 'BSC'
       end as "Network Element Type"
from   nc_objects nt
       join nc_references r
            on r.reference = nt.object_id
from   nc_objects nt;
```

The original version queries `nc_objects`, and for each row, it attempts to use a join of `nc_objects` and `nc_references` in a scalar subquery, which fails as it finds more than one row per `nt object`. If you just want to join these two tables then you don't need a scalar subquery ('select (select)'), as you can just join them as above.

However, the query doesn't use anything from `nc_references` so possibly you don't need to join at all, or else some logic is missing.